# SQL grouping function text display

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a database with a large number of columns that are numerical and a small number of columns that are text.

| Name | salary | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allen | 50000 | Customer Service |
| Violet | 100000 | Engineering |
| Allen | 80000 | Accounting |
| Violet | 75000 | Maintenance |

I would like to group by name and show average salary so my SQL query is:

```
select
     name,
     avg(salary),
     department
from
     table
group by
     name;
```

My question is: What dictates what is going to appear in the department column, and are there any functions where I can control that output? For the above example, if I wanted to make sure the department shown was wherever their salary was greatest, could I force that?

Comment: What RDBMS used? Version?

Comment: YOU will dictate what appears in the department column by supplying an aggregation formula for that column in the SELECT clause jut as you did for `avg(salary)`. You can do `Max(department)` or if you are on an RDBMS that supports it, something like `string_agg(department)` or `listagg(department)`. OR if you are on a version of mysql prior to 5.7 and you run your sql as-is, it will just pick one randomly (yikes). Ultimately this depends on two things. 1) What RDBMS are you using 2)What do you want that output to look like?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 8.0.26. I tried max() and it didn't appear to be accurate, but it's possible I am making a false assumption about my data.

Comment: max will just return the maximum department string, completely unrelated to which salary was greatest.

Comment: what department do you want if there are more than one with the max salary?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
select
     name,
     avg(salary),
     first_value(department) over (order by salary desc) department
from table
group by name;
```

Comment: I've never heard of first_value(), I'll check it otu.

Comment: I believe you need a subquery or a CTE for this; window functions work on the rows *after* grouping, not before

Answer (score 1):

> What dictates what is going to appear in the department column, and are there any functions where I can control that output?

With sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled (which it is by default, from 5.7 on), selecting just `department` will result in a 1055 error.  Without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, an arbitrary department from one of the grouped rows will be returned, and you should not count on it being any particular one.  Just changing to `min(department)` or `max(department)` enables the query to work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, if you don't actually care which department is returned.

Comment: (this is intentionally an answer to only part of the question, and doesn't address what they actually want to acheive)

Answer (score 0):

For old MySQL versions (have not window functions) you can use sub-query;

```
select
     name,
     avg(salary),
     (select max(department) from eployees_salary d where d.name = eployees_salary.name and d.salary = max(eployees_salary.salary)) department
from eployees_salary
group by name;
```

[MySQL sub-query online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=35f50a753bced05920d5912f12bdd9b5&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Since MySQL 8.0 window functions can be used:

```
with d as (
    select name, salary, first_value(department) over (partition by name order by salary desc) department
    from eployees_salary
)
select 
     name,
     avg(salary),
     min(department) department
from d
group by name;
```

[MySQL 8.0 window functions online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=ba5e4d2b6366ed25a32b3c6a65de046d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: is that query accurate? should the department in your select statement just be d? I haven't used with like that before.

Comment: @S.Slusky no, it was not correct.  fixed it to be `from d`

Comment: @S.Slusky `with` is basically a way to give a subquery a name, which is useful if you need to use it more than once or make it recursive.  here, it is no different than just doing `select .. from (the subquery) subquery alias`: `select name, avg(salary), min(department) department from (select name, salary, first_value(department) over (partition by name order by salary desc) department from eployees_salary) d group by name`

Comment: Thank you! This seems like it would be pretty useful. I generally have been shying from subqueries for readability reasons.